# Mac server.app equivalent for Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, mac

In Mac OS X there is the server.app which makes all server related things simple and easy.
Is there something like this for Ubuntu server, or at least something that easily sets up a domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the server version of Ubuntu is just like the regular Ubuntu, less the graphical interface. There exists many third party application (mostly web applications) such as cPanel that provide you with some of the things that server.app allows on Mac servers.

Comment: There was a similar application but I forgot the name and can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Zentyal which can be downloaded from apt-get or just download the zentyal iso, has an excellent management software.  Though its more of a small business server platform.  Webmin works, but ubuntu doesn't recommend it.

Honestly, you should just rock out the command line, in the beginning its hard, but as you get used to it, its faster than any GUI.

Good Luck